# Не изменяется элемент после ajax запроса

Tags: jquery

почему не изменяются

```
$(this).children('.voteUp a').removeClass('icon-vote-up');
$(this).children('.voteUp a').addClass('icon-vote-up2');
$(this).children('.answerVoting .votesNumber').text(data.val);
```

эти параметры, вот код

```
$(".Voting .voteUp").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.Voting').children('input').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id : id vote: 'up'},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.msg){
                    alert(data.msg);
                }else{
                     $(this).children('.voteUp a').removeClass('icon-vote-up');
                     $(this).children('.voteUp a').addClass('icon-vote-up2');
                     $(this).children('.answerVoting .votesNumber').text(data.val);
                }
            }
        });
});

<div class="Voting">
    <div class="votes" data-news="2">
        <div class="voteUp">
            <a class="icon-vote-up"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="votesNumber">1</span>
        <div class="voteDown">
            <a class="icon-vote-down"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="newsId" />
</div>
<div class="Voting">
    <div class="votes" data-news="1">
        <div class="voteUp">
            <a class="icon-vote-up"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="votesNumber">0</span>
        <div class="voteDown">
            <a class="icon-vote-down"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="newsId" />
</div>
```

Comment: скрипт то хоть в `<script>` и `$(function(){}` заключен ?

Comment: да заключен

Comment: @FunnY77, у Вас в строке  data: {id : id vote: 'up'} - запятая пропущена

Answer (score 2):

У вас `$(this)` это `$(".Voting .voteUp")`  - у него нет указанных вами детей...

надо как-то так:

```
var $parent=$(this).parent('votes');
$parent.find('.voteUp a').removeClass('icon-vote-up').addClass('icon-vote-up2');    
$parent.find('.answerVoting .votesNumber').text(data.val);  //тут я не вижу класса answerVoting вообще.
```

Comment: спасибо работал